# Get custom attribute from selected option from datalist

Tags: javascript, html

When I choose an option from the datalist I want to get its custom attribute "location" and print it. I know that select has selectedIndex but how do I accomplish this using datalist?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="StartingAddressField" size="50" placeholder="Select item from list" list="select">
  <datalist id="select" style="display:none;" onchange="Select1Changed();">
  <option value="one" location="3"/>
  <option value="two" location="15"/>
  <option value="three" location="27"/>
  </datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `Element.getAttribute()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute): `document.getElementById('select').children[index].getAttribute('location')`.

Comment: This returns the attribute of an element, but how do I know which option I selected from the datalist?

Comment: What does the function "Select1Changed();" do?

Comment: You have to loop through the datalist options and find the one whose value is equal to the one in the input. I am going to add an answer with a code snippet, for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by selecting the element using `document.getElementById` you are getting `HTMLCollection` which you can iterate(in you case option list) and find the desired attribute using the attribute object attached to each element.

Also i found that datalist is not available once value is selected if that is desired then okay else you may look into that bug.

```js
function Select1Changed(elem) {
  let location = 'please select a valid option';
  let dt = document.getElementById('select');
  // dt contains a HTMLCollection of options so use for loop to iterate it use childElementCount to get the length if loop
  for (let i = 0; i < dt.childElementCount; i++) {
    // check the selected value with option values.
    if (dt.children[i].attributes.value.value === elem.value) {
      // if Hit use the attributes object to find your attribute and get its value.
      location = dt.children[i].attributes.location.value;
    }
  }
  alert(location);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="StartingAddressField" size="50" placeholder="Select item from list" list="select" onchange="Select1Changed(this);">
  <datalist id="select" style="display:none;">
  <option value="one" location="3"/>
  <option value="two" location="15"/>
  <option value="three" location="27"/>
  </datalist>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dataList = document.getElementById('select');
const textInput = document.getElementById('StartingAddressField');

const getSelecteOptionLocation = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < dataList.options.length; i++) {
    if (dataList.options[i].value === textInput.value) {
      return dataList.options[i];
    }
  }
}

textInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const selectedOption = getSelecteOptionLocation();
  if (selectedOption == undefined) {
    console.log('option not included in the datalist');
  } else {
    console.log(selectedOption.getAttribute('location'));
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="StartingAddressField" size="50" placeholder="Select item from list" list="select" onBlur="getSelecteOptionLocation()">
  <datalist id="select" style="display:none;">
      <option value="one" location="3" />
      <option value="two" location="15" />
      <option value="three" location="27" />
    </datalist>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Both this solution and sandeep joshi works but if I press enter for a value that is not inside the input it shows error. Should I make another question for how this case needs to be handled? Because I now understand I need to detect if the input text has changed upon pressing "enter" as well.

Comment: @MichaelEffraimidis, you can handle the case with a simple conditional statement. I updated the snippet to handle the scenario;